# What IOS A.P.I Should I be learning to draw smooth curves with adjustable points

Tags: ios, plot, core-graphics

I have never really done much with IOS drawing API's before. I looking into drawing a smooth plot like curve with a programmable number of control points, something similar to this:

[Sample Graph http://blog.mixonline.com/briefingroom/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/eq-editing-screen.jpg](http://blog.mixonline.com/briefingroom/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/eq-editing-screen.jpg)

(I realize that there's a ton math behind the sample graph, I just want to start out with manipulating simple points).

My first thought was that I should be looking into using UIBezierPath Quad paths. I found that this works really well if I have just a start point, end point and control point. I've had a lot of trouble getting curves to look 'sensible' if I try to add a chain of quads to simulate the example I posted.

Basically I just have a lot of doubt about the correct approach to take. Can somebody advise me on where I should be directing my attention?

Comment: Have you tried CorePlot?

Comment: no, I haven't heard of it before. I'll look it up

Comment: there are lots of types of curves in computer graphics. what's the final application? Are you trying to show a filter response curve? Or quadratic bezier curves? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on Core Plot. Here is a multi part tutorial from ray's web site that is going to be a great help to you in order to start with core plot.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Happy coding my friend